# What's wrong in this proof of $i^2=1$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Complex number $i=\sqrt{-1}$

Now i consider  $$\frac{1}{i}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{-1}}=\frac{\sqrt{1}}{\sqrt{-1}}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{-1}}=\sqrt{-1}=i$$

so $$i^2=1$$

Comment: This is due to the illness of the definition of $\sqrt{}$ sign over complex numbers. Generally, there are $n$ branches of the function $x^{\frac{1}{n}}$

Comment: The rule $\sqrt{u}/\sqrt{v}=\sqrt{u/v}$ does not generally hold for complex numbers $u$ and $v$.

Comment: This post is good: https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/3k5125/why_exactly_is_1_1_11_1_1_i²_1_impossible/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if $1=\sqrt{1}$
Then

$e^{i2\pi}=e^{i\pi}$

See your error?